# Java URLEncoding / Decoding URL Spaces with dashes

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm looking to encode filter parameters within a URL. I'd like a readable URL so I'd like to replace spaces with underscores.

Example aston martin encoded to aston_martin and not aston$0020martin. I would then need to be able to decode the URL back to aston martin.

My only concern is with search parameters naturally containing underscores. I'm not sure what you would do in this particular use case.

I'm a tapestry5 user, so I do have the option to override the URLEcoder, or could use the java URLEncoder. I just haven't figured out how to get it to encode things the way I'd like them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the standard encoding of "+" for space?

Comment: @TedHopp I guess your correct. I'm not sure why I was thinking I needed to do it with spaces. I guess I was just thinking SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing URL-encoding with java.net.URLEncoder. Not surprising, and not your fault. Despite its name, the latter process is for URL *argument* names and values, and the same in POST data. It is only the former that turns space into %20. The latter turns it into '+', which is (a) the correct thing to do for your filter parameters, (b) reversible, and (c) not as offensive as %20. Don't know where you got $0020 from.

Comment: I'm not sure why my question was voted down as this is a real question :( anyhow my current URLEncoder which I believe is Tapestries built in URLEncoder is replacing spaces with $0020, something I didn't think was as clean / readable as _ or +. I'll look into your suggestion and try to figure out how to use + signs.

Comment: @George java.net.URLEncoder does that for you. I have no idea what this Tapestries thing thinks it' doing. The RFCs specify %20 within the URL proper and + in an argument.