# Javascript replace % with $00 in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer, replace, tapestry

As expected I need to encode a URI component before I call an API using it but when it hits our server somewhere along the line our backend framework (tapestry) converts spaces too early: [Java URLEncoding / Decoding URL Spaces with dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944672/java-urlencoding-decoding-url-spaces-with-dashes)

I figured out that if I changed the URI %20 to $0020 it works. So the code below works in Chrome and Firefox and converts the % to a $00.

```
function furtherEncode(uriComp) {
  var nonSafe = encodeURIComponent(uriComp);
  return nonSafe.replace(/%/g, "$00");
}
```

In Internet Explorer 11 (and IE10) it doesn't do the replacement.

I have tried `/\x25/g` and `/%/g` as well as `"$00"` and `'$00'` but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's why you must prohibit spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two dollar signs like here (tested in IE and Chrome):

```
"%".replace(/%/g, "$$00") /// returns  "$00"
```

See docs here: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Relevant parts are defined under "Specifying a string as a parameter":

```
$$ | Inserts a "$".
$n | Where n or nn are decimal digits, inserts the nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument was a RegExp object
```